# Releasing Outlets in a NavigationController

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller, iboutlet

I have literally 24 IBOutlets in one view of a NavigationController (none are retained as properties). Is there a good way to release these? I have a feeling they are causing memory issues in slower 3G and 3GS devices.

No ARC

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not using ARC, I update the question

Comment: In iOS IBOutlets are retained by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you push UIViewControllers on to a UINavigationController, the view of the UIViewControllers which have been "pushed onto" may be unloaded to save memory (as they are invisible). The views are then reloaded when necessary (and you get the viewDidLoad callback). You should have IBOutlets to UIViewControllers not UINavigationController so that they can be released on viewDidUnload. The usual way to release them is to declare them as retained properties and set them to nil (with the self.outlet accessor) in viewDidUnload and dealloc. Or just use ARC.

Answer (score 0):

### ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myLabel;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setMyLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [myLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```